# Nuget update to latest version with teamcity

Tags: nuget, teamcity, nuget-package, teamcity-9.0

Our builds use a mix of internally generated nuget packages and external third party ones. All package configs have allowedVersions="[1,3)" set on them to allow updating to the latest version as per https://docs.nuget.org/create/versioning.

We are also using the nuget restore step as described here https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/NuGet+Installer but we cant get it to update to the latest versions of the nuget packages.

To test we deleted the version of the package that was expected in the packages.config and left later versions intact. This should have caused nuget restore step to find that the current version isnt available and update to the latest version. Instead the step fails with unable to restore the specific version in the packages.config file.

If we run an update package command locally in visual studio the install works as expected, what are we missing?

Comment: were you able to solve this?